# Selecting list of elements within specific class: CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been Google-ing around for the past half hour trying to see if there is a solution to this problem, but I'm not having any luck with finding any answers.

Inquiry: Is it possible to select and apply css to a list of elements within a specific class?

Specific to my case: selecting all the header elements found within the class .feature-headline

```
.feature-headline h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

When I try it with the code above, it results in the css selecting each and every header element, not just the ones found within the class.

Curious to know if this is even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in CSS, if you wish to apply style conditions to all HTML headers that are classed as "feature-headline", then the correct approach is:

```
.feature-headline h1, .feature-headline h2, .feature-headline h3, .feature-headline h4, .feature-headline h5, .feature-headline h6 {
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

What you've listed basically tells the computer: provide the 'text-transform' property to header 1 (H1) with the class .feature-headline, and also apply it to all other headers (regardless of class), too.

The best method I can think of in order to solve this problem is through SASS, where you can nest:

```
.feature-headline {
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5, h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

Comment: LESS is also able to nest

Comment: Thanks a ton for clarifying this.

Comment: @Mephiztopheles That's correct! LESS is a good alternative to CSS, too